# Updating Integer value in Mysql/VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mariadb

```
    SQL = "UPDATE `tblitems` SET `itemsOnHand` = `itemsOnHand` - '" & PartnumItemsNumericUpDown.Value & "' WHERE `itemID` = '" & itemIDTextBoxX.Text & "' ;"


    SQL = "UPDATE `tblitems` SET `itemsOnHand` = `itemsOnHand` + '" & PartnumItemsNumericUpDown.Value & "' WHERE `itemID` = '" & itemIDTextBoxX.Text & "' ;"
```

--- Just want to ask why the first sub function sql command (-) works but (+) wont...please help. itemsOnHand is integer type.

Comment: Assuming PartnumItemsNumericUpDown.Value is an integer, you should remove the single quotes. The same is probably true around itemIDTextBoxX.Text. I am pretty sure that the reason - works and + doesn't is because followed by a text value + does concatenation, whereas - is always interpreted as a mathematical operation, so the string gets parsed as numeric

Comment: Further to the above comment, what do double-quotes do in VB? The denote a literal string, right? Do you put double-quotes around numbers in VB code? Of course not, because they are not literal strings. Single-quotes denote literal strings in SQL code so the rest should be fairly obvious. You should also learn how to use parameters in ADO.NET code. Issues like this just go away if you do things properly, i.e. use parameters.

Comment: Thank you sirs for the quick response. I tried your suggestions, but removing the single quotes produces syntax problems. , I'll apply parameters, need to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Please **DO NOT** concatenate strings to build sql command text. **ALWAYS** use `Parameters` it avoid sql injection. Parameter values are not executable code but a simple concatenation can hold "Delete * From tblitems."

I had to guess at the datatypes for the parameters.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ItemId As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(itemIDTextBoxX.Text, ItemId) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in Item Id.")
        Return
    End If
    Dim Sql = "UPDATE `tblitems` SET `itemsOnHand` = `itemsOnHand` - @PartNumber WHERE `itemID` = @ItemID"
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand(Sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PartNumber", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = PartnumItemsNumericUpDown.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = ItemID
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

You are much less likely to run into problems with + and - using parameters since you don't need all the single quotes and double quotes.

The minus sign was interpreted as an arithmetic operator and the plus sign was interpreted as a concatenation character.

Comment: I would love to learn using parameters and I tried using your code. My connections settings are defined using a module.                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                           
        Public Function sqlConn() As MySqlConnection
        Return New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;password=mypassword;database=motorpooldb")
    End Function

    Public conn As MySqlConnection = sqlConn()

Comment: And I have this in my form.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Imports System.IO
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class frmDDMaint

    Public myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Public myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Public myData As New DataTable
    Public SQL As String
    Public dr As MySqlDataReader

Comment: I will try to make it work, i'l give updates on my progress.

Comment: @sokovi It is a bad idea to declare database objects outside the method where they are used. Connections, Commands and DataReaders need to be Disposed as well as closed. They use unmanaged resources internally and to properly release these resources, the `.Dispose` method of these objects must be called. The .net framework provides `Using...End Using` blocks which handle this for us. Once disposed, your from level variable will be nothing.

Comment: @sokovi Please check the datatypes in the database because I had to guess at their types.